# How do I get a hamburger menu to hide when clicking a menu item that links to a section on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu

```
$('.menu-icon').click(function(event) {
       if ( $( '.menu-icon' ).hasClass( 'open' ) ) {
            $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('open');
            $('header').toggleClass('remove-bg');
            $('nav').fadeOut();
            $('#dot').show();
        } else {
            $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('open');
            $('header').toggleClass('remove-bg');
            $('nav').css("display", "flex").hide().fadeIn();
            $('#dot').hide();
        }
    });
```

The menu stays open but I want it to close when I click a menu item like About which links to #about

Comment: Something like `$('#dot a').click(function() { $('#dot').hide() })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below

```
$('.full-screen a').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu-icon').toggleClass('open');
    $('header').toggleClass('remove-bg');
    $('nav').fadeOut();
    $('#dot').show();
})
```